# Python: get data from a table from website

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath

I want to get the data from table from https://www.sgx.com/securities/stock-screener.
However, I found that the html unable to locate the xpath that direct to the table. 
I am using Python 2.7

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.sgx.com/securities/stock-screener')
data = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it is a js rendered page

Comment: Yes. The content is dynamically generated.

Comment: @Alejandro, anyways to get the data in this case? using other modules in python?

Comment: @Alejandro, alternative is to get the url for download but unable to find in page source

Comment: Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or alternatives.